# Azure AD B2C - Can we restrict concurrent logins of a user in azure adb2c?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We have developed custom policies for the signin and signup of users for our application (both web and mobile). Can we restrict the concurrent login of a user in multiple applications or multiple sessions of same application?

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Srivalli

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot using b2c alone, you’d need your own session tracker which you might use via a rest api.

Comment: Azure AD B2C session is a cookie based session. Thus, if users sings-in with different browsers, devices, or even using different custom domains, each one of them has its own session (cookie). As Jas has mentioned to control all of them in a central place, a custom session tracker must be deployed.